# Set One Slide Size/Orientation Without Changing Whole Presentation in PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there a way to set or insert a blankslide with a different orientation/size to the other slides in the presentation. Everything I am aware of changes the whole presentation. Thank you

```
ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideOrientation = msoOrientationVertical
ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight = 720
ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth = 720
```

Comment: ^^^^ Meaning the answer is no. If you can't do it manually, you can't do it with VBA either.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Having a different orientation in a presentation for screen does not make sense, so you're probably not planning a screen presentation. So, what are you planning to do?

Comment: @teylyn Lots of people use PPT to create printed documents, so it'd be convenient to be able to mix portrait and landscape oriented pages in the same file. But we can't.